# Отправка формы, ошибка 405

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

У меня есть форма отправки на сайте:

```
<form id="form" class="form__body" action="" method="post">
                                                        <div>
                                                            <div class="b24-form-field b24-form-field-name b24-form-control-string">
                                                                <div>
                                                                    <div>
                                                                        <div class="b24-form-control-container b24-form-control-icon-after" >
                                                                            <input name="name" id="form-name" autocomplete="given-name" type="string" class="b24-form-control _req" style="background-color:rgb(247, 247, 247); border: 0px; " required>
                                                                            <div class="b24-form-control-label">Имя
                                                                                <span class="b24-form-control-required">*</span>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="b24-form-field b24-form-field-company-name b24-form-control-string">
                                                                <div>
                                                                    <div>
                                                                        <div class="b24-form-control-container b24-form-control-icon-after">
                                                                            <input name="company" id="form-company" type="string" class="b24-form-control _req" style="background-color:rgb(247, 247, 247); border: 0px;" required>
                                                                            <div class="b24-form-control-label">Название компании 
                                                                                <span class="b24-form-control-required">*</span>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="b24-form-field b24-form-field-phone b24-form-control-string">
                                                                <div>
                                                                    <div>
                                                                        <div class="b24-form-control-container b24-form-control-icon-after">
                                                                            <input name="phone" id="form-phone" autocomplete="tel" type="tel" class="mask-phone b24-form-control _req" style="background-color:rgb(247, 247, 247); border: 0px;" required>
                                                                            <div class="b24-form-control-label">Телефон 
                                                                                <span class="b24-form-control-required">*</span>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="b24-form-field b24-form-field-email b24-form-control-string">
                                                                <div>
                                                                    <div>
                                                                        <div class="b24-form-control-container b24-form-control-icon-after">
                                                                            <input name="email" id="form-email" autocomplete="email" type="text" class="b24-form-control _req _email" style="background-color:rgb(247, 247, 247); border: 0px;" required>
                                                                            <div class="b24-form-control-label">E-mail 
                                                                                <span class="b24-form-control-required">*</span>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="b24-form-field b24-form-field-text b24-form-control-text">
                                                                <div>
                                                                    <div>
                                                                        <div class="b24-form-control-container b24-form-control-icon-after">
                                                                            <textarea name="comment" id="form-comment" class="b24-form-control" style="background-color:rgb(247, 247, 247); border: 0px;" placeholder=" "></textarea>
                                                                            <div class="b24-form-control-label">Комментарий 
                                                                                <span class="b24-form-control-required" style="display: none;">*</span>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <div class="b24-form-control-alert-message" style="display: none;"></div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div>
                                                            <div class="b24-form-field b24-form-field-agreement b24-form-control-agreement">
                                                                <div>
                                                                    <label class="b24-form-control-container">
                                                                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox__input _req" required onclick="this.blur()" checked="checked">
                                                                        <span class="b24-form-control-desc">
                                                                            <span class="b24-form-field-agreement-link ">Нажимая кнопку «Отправить», я даю свое согласие на обработку моих персональных данных</span>
                                                                        </span>
                                                                        <span class="b24-form-control-required">*</span>
                                                                        <div class="b24-form-control-alert-message" style="display: none;"></div>
                                                                    </label>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="v-portal" style="display: none;"></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="b24-form-btn-container">
                                                            <div class="b24-form-btn-block">
                                                                <button type="submit" class="b24-form-btn">Отправить</button>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </form>
```

Также в этом же файле есть js:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery("form").submit(function() { // Событие отправки с формы
                var form_data = jQuery(this).serialize(); // Собираем данные из полей
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "/senda.php", // Путь к PHP обработчику sendform.php
                    method: "POST", // Метод отправки
                    data: form_data,
                    success: swal({
                        title: "Спасибо за заявку!",
                        type: "success",
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        timer: 2000
                    })
                });
                $(this).find('input, textarea').prop('disabled', true);
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
</script>
```

js отправляет форму в обработчик:

```
<?php
    $name = trim($_POST['name']); 
    $company = trim($_POST['company']); 
    $phone = trim($_POST['phone']); 
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $comment = trim($_POST['comment']);
    $fromMail = 'info@verstach.ru'; 
    $fromName = 'Поступила заявка с сайта'; //Заголовок письма
    $emailTo = 'www@mail.ru'; 
    $subject = 'Форма обратной связи site.com'; 
    $subject = '=?utf-8?b?'. base64_encode($subject) .'?='; 
    $headers = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "From: ". $fromName ." <". $fromMail ."> \r\n"; 
        
    // Содержимое письма 
    $body = "Получено письмо с сайта \n Имя: $name\nКампания: $company\nТелефон: $phone\nEmail: $email\nКомментарий: $comment";     
    $mail = mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers, '-f'. $fromMail ); 
    return;
```

Но как только я отправляю форму, возникает ошибка 405 (Method Not Allowed), которая ссылается на мой обработчик. Ошибка это говорит о том, что данные отправляются, но что то не так с файлом php. Может кто то объяснить, что не так делаю?

P.s все библиотеки и файлы подключены, тестирую на локалке, спасибо

Comment: А вы уверены, что запрос до файла php вообще доходит? Вдруг веб-сервер не настроен на запуск php-кода по адресу /senda.php

Comment: Не уверена. Форма отправляется, а дальше вот вопросы. А как можно посмотреть?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте JS использовать такой

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function() {
        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/senda.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: form_data,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
        $(this).find('input, textarea').prop('disabled', true);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

а в `senda.php` добавить в конец вместо `return;` такой ответ (буде возвращаться в response)

```
echo 'Спасибо за заявку!';
```

и показать его где-то на странице.

Comment: Ранее я нажимала на кнопку и видела уведомление "спасибо за за явку!", а сейчас кнопка не нажимается вовсе(

Comment: И все равно 405 появляется

Comment: Добавил другой ответ.

Comment: И с этим кодом тоже пробовала, ошибка 405 так и выскакивает

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы использовать библиотеку SweetAlert (функция swal), ее нужно сначала подключить.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var scr = document.createElement('script');   
    scr.src = "https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js";
    var doc = document.getElementById ('form');
    doc.appendChild(scr);
    $("form").submit(function() {
        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/senda.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: form_data,
            success: swal({
                title: "Спасибо за заявку!",
                type: "success",
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 2000
            })
        });
        $(this).find('input, textarea, button').prop('disabled', true);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```